# Invisible mouse on 14.04 with NVIDIA GeForce4 Ti 4200

Tags: graphics, mouse

I installed a fresh install of Xubuntu 14.04 and the mouse is not visible on my screen. It works, but it seems to be invisible.

How can I get it on screen?

I had the same problem on a Ubuntu 14.04 Live-CD so it seems to be a problem with my graphics card in Ubuntu in general.

I tried earlier `apt-get install nvidia-173` which worked on my old Monitor, but then I couldn't access the desktop anymore with my **only 1024x768 LCD-Display**, so I had to reinstall.

Maybe a solution would be to configure a right `xorg.conf` with the old nvidia-173 driver for my computer, but there is no `xorg.conf` anymore in `/etc/X11` so this seems to have changed in 14.04 too.

How would I have to create such a file?

Comment: Make sure you have done a full system update (in a terminal do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`). If the mouse pointer is still not visible then report the bug on Launchpad. You could try the proprietary drivers as a workaround.

Comment: This might be related http://askubuntu.com/questions/381362/missing-mouse-after-gnome-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time it worked installing

```
apt-get install nvidia-common
```

**Important:**
Don't run `nvidia-config` and **don't** create any `xorg.conf` file now!

Then reboot

```
apt-get install nvidia-173
```

reboot

I don't know if there has to be several reboots, but the first time I tried it without installing `nvidia-common` first and this messed up with my resolution for my LCD monitor